# Where can I see logs or details for error Azure "An error has occurred." for an API call on Azure?

Tags: asp.net, azure, api, rest

I have an ASP.NET API and works great as local and using Postman.

Then I decided to publish to Azure since I tried on other free host SOMEE and never worked.

Principal API page on Azure works fine but when I tried to call a controller shows the error

{"Message":"An error has occurred."}

and I don't even know where to check more details about this error.

I tried the same on a Somee.com host and same thing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure portal offer to you some resources to investigate your issue

- Log stream (in your App Service page, under Monitoring section), can give you some info of you api call.
  [image]
- Advanced Tools (in your App Service page, under Development Tools), can give you more information of your app settings, deployment info, wwwroot folder, etc...
  [image]

It can be a deployment issue(related to the app service configuration, maybe you are using a docker container?) or a simple error in your connection string, so review your app service settings:
[image]

it's usually one of these(some) problems.

all the best

Comment: Not really, but it was helpful I got to see the entire error details, now I don't know what I'm missing haha I created another question with the details, maybe you can help me

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63121389/azure-asp-net-api-iis-was-not-able-to-access-the-web-config-file

Comment: Btw something weird I found is that mine doesn't show the Browse Directory part