# Fix "Message": "An error has occurred." in my api

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, entity-framework

I build a api and when I publish the erro "Message": "An error has occurred." is happen.

I make a add-migration and delete the file. When create other  file with add-migration and make a update-database. This work in my machine, but when I publish in the Microsoft azure I always receive "Message": "An error has occurred.".

I [read about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63108077/where-can-i-see-logs-or-details-for-error-azure-an-error-has-occurred-for-an) see the Log stream. But this is my Log Stream :

[image: Log stream]

I look for the variable SCM_LOGSTREAM_TIMEOUT but can't find. Can help me ?

Comment: In `Azure portal` => Your `Web App` => `Configuration` => `Application Settings`, add this key `SCM_LOGSTREAM_TIMEOUT ` with value `1800`.

Comment: What is the `.net framework` version you are using ?

Comment: I have checked my Azure Web App `Log Stream`, even it is displaying the [same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stL7S.png).It is the default message which we get to change the default TimeOut if you wish to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have deployed Azure Web API and checked the `Log Stream`.

If `Application Service logs` are set to off, we get the below error.

[image]

Once we enable `Application Service logs`, by default we get the below message in Log Console.

[image]

By default, it suggests us to increase the TimeOut in Azure App Settings if required.
The default timeout is 2 hours (7200 sec).

> I look for the variable SCM_LOGSTREAM_TIMEOUT but can't find. Can help me ?

In  `Azure portal`  => Navigate to your  `Web App`  =>  click on `Configuration`   Under `Settings` =>  `Application Settings`, add New Application setting with the key  `SCM_LOGSTREAM_TIMEOUT` and value  which you want (In Seconds).